# How to route line in to speakers on debian with alsa?

Tags: debian, alsa, loopback

How can I route line in to speakers, loopback-style with alsa?  I've seen a few solutions using GUIs but I don't have a desktop UI installed. I've also seen a solution with PulseAudio, but I'd prefer not to have to install more packages and deal with extra configuration.

Is it possible to do this strictly with alsa? Sorry, I'm new to alsa and sound devices in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [alsamixer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer) program, unmuting and adjusting the setting for your Line connection in the Playback section. It should allow you to do that through its terminal interface. To save the settings so that they remain the same after a reboot, you need to run `alsactl store` as root after you make your changes.

Comment: Ah, this worked. It was mic that had the volume though, not line. Thanks!